# C++ Que tipo de pausa de pantalla es más eficiente

Tags: c++

he visto varios tipos de pausa implementados en C++ por ej:

```
getch()
cin.get()
system("pause>nul")
```

Pero quisiera saber cual de ellos es el mas correcto o recomendado de usar, o si no hay una diferencia alguna

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hay** varias diferencias:

```
#include<stdlib.h>
system( "pause > null" );
```

Eso solo funciona si existe una orden `pause` que el *intérprete de comandos* del sistema operativo pueda ejecutar. En Linux, por ejemplo, da error de `orden no encontrada`.

Además, usa mas recursos que las demás: necesita llamar a un programa externo (el intérprete de órdenes); si éste reconoce la orden, la ejecutará. Si no la reconoce, llamará a otro programa (o dará error). Un despilfarro, vamos.

```
#include<conio.h>
getch( );
```

Esto **no es portable**. Depende de que la librería usada la proporcione, pero no podemos suponer que exista en todos los compiladores. Mismo ejemplo que en el anterior: en Linux, **no** funciona.

```
#include<iostream>
cin.get( );
```

Esta es la forma correcta. Pertenece al estándar C++, por lo que estará presente en todos los compiladores que se ajusten a él.

Comment: muchas gracias amigo, siempre tenia esas dudas